# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by FFmpeg when deployed on Linux as a packaged .war (Works on development machine)

Tags: java, linux, maven, ffmpeg

I use an FFmpeg wrapper to create thumbnails for videos uploaded by users. This works perfectly fine when testing on my development machine. However, whenever I package my project as a .war and deploy to Amazon Web Services, I get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:472) ~[javacpp-1.2.1.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:417) ~[javacpp-1.2.1.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2597) ~[ffmpeg-2.8.1-1.1.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:391) ~[javacv-1.2.jar!/:1.2]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:385) ~[javacv-1.2.jar!/:1.2]
    at com.myapp.app.service.ICampaignService.createThumbnail(ICampaignService.java:425) ~[classes!/:0.0.44T-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.myapp.app.service.ICampaignService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$47736265.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.44T-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.myapp.app.service.ICampaignService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67e59894.createThumbnail(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.44T-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.myapp.app.controllers.CampaignController.uploadCampaign(CampaignController.java:237) ~[classes!/:0.0.44T-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Here's my maven dependencies for the FFmpeg wrapper:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1-1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Again, this library works perfectly fine on my development machine.

- Development machine: Windows 10, 64-bit (Works)
- AWS instance:64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.2.0 running Java 8 (Causes the issue above)

I've spent around 7 hours trying to fix the issue by messing around with versions. Any idea how to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco:javacv:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:jar:1.9.6-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:0.200-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:jar:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:android-arm:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:android-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-armhf:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-ppc64le:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:macosx-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:windows-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:windows-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servicecatalog:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servermigration:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-budgets:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-events:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codepipeline:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directory:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-efs:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codecommit:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-devicefarm:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-waf:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-inspector:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-gamelift:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dms:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacemeteringservice:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-discovery:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationautoscaling:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-snowball:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.11.58:compile
[INFO]    \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22:compile
```

Error after upgrading Linux to 2.4, downgrading javacpp to 1.2.1, and running mvn clean:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:472) ~[javacpp-1.2.1.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:417) ~[javacpp-1.2.1.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2819) ~[ffmpeg-3.2.1-1.3.jar!/:1.2.1]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:391) ~[javacv-1.3.jar!/:1.3]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:385) ~[javacv-1.3.jar!/:1.3]
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

- upgrade to Linux to 2.4
- downgrading javacpp to 1.2.1
- running mvn clean
- running mvn -U
- deleting contents of /.m2/ and redownloading dependencies
- various combinations of dependency versions
- `git clone` on a Linux VM & running `mvn install` there

Comment: did you download the dependency in your project.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh Yes. All of the jars are there in my Maven dependencies. Even the Linux support jar is there. (In the javacpp-presets dependency)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of version switching and Maven cleaning, I finally got it to work. No need to clone on a Linux VM.

- Maven clean
- Remove unnecessary / duplicate dependencies in your pom.xml
- Delete your /.m2/repository folder containing all dependency jars
- Run maven build to reinstall all dependencies
- Maven install and your packaged .war shouldn't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you need to update your glibc to 2.14 
Check https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/issues/106

Comment: Updated my linux version to: `64bit Amazo in Linux 2016.09 v2.4.0 running Java 8`. Still getting the same error. I'm not very familiar with Linux. Was this the appropriate thing to do? Or is there another process to update my Linux instance's glibc? I'm still having the same problem after updating to 2.4

Comment: glibc version is 2.17. Learned how to use Linux today

Answer (score 0):

This sort of errors can be considered as a **Class-Loader-related error**, also known as [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell). In most of the cases, the class loader is trying to lookup a class/method in runtime and do not find that what he was expecting to find.

You probably would face this kind of problems more often, when you are working on a bigger Java project with a lot of external dependencies (which again have dependencies and so on...).

There are several approaches to solving this kind of problems, one pretty good is:

**Check your dependency tree:**

run `mvn clean` to clean up the possible noise. Then run
`mvn dependency:tree -U > deps.txt`
The `-U` flag, force maven to update/download the newest SNAPSHOT versions of your dependent libraries.

A look inside of `deps.txt` would yield a tree structure of all your dependencies in your maven project. It would look as follow:

```
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.11:jar:3.1.1:compile
```

As you can see, it is a tree structure showing your libraries and their dependent libraries. As next try to look for version mismatches (e.g t*wo different versions of the same library in the same scope*).

Example:

```
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.my.fancy:library:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.8:compile
```

As you can see, the **fancy** library contain another **joda-time** version than **jackson-core**. Both are in the `compile` scope. This can result in a runtime error because the class loader could try to get a method/class of **joda:time:1.8** but being in scope of **jackson-core** that is required **joda:time:2.3**.

To resolve this you could explicitly exclude one joda time version from your scope (in your `pom.xml`):

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.my.fancy</groupId>
     <artifactId>library</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
         <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Hope this will give you a good first introduction. There is no universall solution for the JAR Hell, if you have more question feel free to reply this answer and we will figure out!

Ivan

Comment: I ran the maven command: `mvn dependency:tree -U > deps.txt` and posted my dependency tree. There's no duplicate dependencies as far as I can tell. I posted the dependency tree if you want to take a look. I'm going to repackage and deploy to see if it may have fixed the issue.

Comment: @jakeMiller I would guess that the repackaging will solve your problem. As you can see in your error stack trace, the classloader try to load `javacpp-1.2.1.jar` - in your dependency tree you have the `javacpp version 1.3`. Try ```mvn clean``` if this not work also try to empty the `~/.m2/` folder in your home directory.

Comment: Should I downgrade my javacpp version to 1.2.1? The other bytedeco dependencies may require version 1.2.1?

Comment: @JakeMiller do this if the repackaging not works for you! 
If you want to dive into and find out what is actually is going on, you can try to add this routine, to the spot where the exception occurs (e.g the part of your code that is initial to the exception). This part will show you what the class loader actually try to load.

 `println("------------------------------------------------")`
 `println(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(<YourErrorClass>.getClass.getName.replace(".","/") + ".class"))`
`println("------------------------------------------------")`

Comment: So far, upgrading to Linux, downgrading to javacpp 1.2.1, running mvn clean, and then repackaging did not work. Getting the same error. I deleted the contents of my /.m2/ folder and am running mvn build currently. Will repackage and deploy to see if that solves the issue. Also, should I run the println statements within the bytedeco class? Or in the class I created that utilizes this class?

Comment: In your class! Btw. is it an open source project or something? Do you have the code on git?

Comment: It's not open source unfortunately. I can post a code snippet of what I'm trying to do if you want. I don't think it'll be of much help as it works perfectly fine on my machine, just not when I deploy to AWS (Running Linux 2.4). The line in my code that causes an error is simply an instantiation of a `FFmpegFrameGrabber` object. This line specifically: `FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(tempVideoFile);` where `tempVideoFile` is a temporary `File` object created using a `MultipartFile` uploaded by a user.

Comment: Same error even after deleting my /.m2/ directory. I'm unsure as to what to do next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131521/discussion-between-jake-miller-and--allquantor-).

Comment: Same issue... Even after cloning on linux and doing mvn install there.